# Find all IP addresses within */log/* directories and output these lines to a file, without duplicates

Tags: ubuntu, grep, find, regular-expression, sort

I am trying to retrieve all lines with IP addresses from files within directories called `log` and write them to a file, but I'm not having much luck. At the moment I'm typing in:

```
find . -path "*/log/*" -type f | xargs grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" | xargs grep -v "[myip]" > log.txt | sort -u
```

But this just outputs the following:

```
Binary file ./var/log/wtmp.1 matches
Binary file ./var/log/lastlog matches
Binary file ./var/log/btmp matches
Binary file ./var/log/btmp.1 matches
Binary file ./var/log/wtmp matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-00000000000334f4-000547883cd64bfc.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-000000000003109b-000547834461e9ac.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-000000000002ec72-0005477e385a43c7.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-000000000002c42c-0005477bb1a39b46.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-0000000000029d35-00054776e06fb915.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-0000000000027310-000547743bc488ca.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-0000000000024a25-00054771307a13d2.journal matches
Binary file ./run/log/journal/9dec9e4e32834bb59a2d5e1c50895ca5/system@4d01f718aa76471eafb1b2faa76e05e2-0000000000022116-0005476e66afb18c.journal matches
```

Which isn't at all what I'm after. I need to write this query correctly? Ideally the output should look something like this:

```
Started GET "/" for [IP] at 2017-02-02 19:15:39 +0000
Cannot render console from 85.248.227.164! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
[...]
Jan 29 06:25:04 ubuntu sshd[24085]: Failed password for root from [IP] port 41348 ssh2
```

And so forth, excluding my IP address and any related results. Ideally with the file path and line number prepended to each match.

```
find . -path "*/log/*" -type f | exec grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" {} > log.txt
```

Doesn't output anything to log file. Part of the problem seems to be with the additional processes, as

```
find . -path "*/log/*" -type f | xargs grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" > log.txt
```

Does output IP addresses, it just gets a lot of duplicate stuff and loads of results with my IP, which I don't want.

Comment: *"isn't at all what I'm after"* how exactly? do you want a better regex for IP addresses? or to exclude binary files? or exclude ephemeral filesystems such as `/run`?

Comment: Well, at the moment, it's not including the lines which include the IP addresses at all... Though I just had an idea...

Comment: instead of `| xargs grep` have you tried `exec grep...... {} +` ? assuming that your regex is good

Comment: doesn't seem to... (adding to answer)

Comment: To strip out duplicates after the `grep -o`, pipe through `| sort | uniq`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti that's really useful; I have a lot closer to what I wanted now. Very much more usable than the output I was getting before.

Comment: @DopeGhoti or even `sort -u`, since the OP doesn't appear to need to do anything special with the uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work using :

```
regex="(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
sudo find / -path "*/log/*" -type f -exec grep -Eo $regex {} +
```

Pipe it through `sort` if you want it sorted, and add the redirection to have it in a file.

```
sudo find / -path "*/log/*" -type f -exec grep -Eo $regex {} + \
  | grep -v "[myip]" | sort | uniq > log.txt
```

Comment: I was wanting to exclude my own IP address rather than find mentions of it... though now I'm able to sort to unique it's not really critical to exclude.

Comment: `find / -path "*/log/*"` could probably be replaced with `find /var/log/`

Comment: as a general rule, but I have some ruby on rails log files I'm also wanting to look though, and there's a lot of useful stuff there too

Comment: yeah i misunderstood, i will update the answer

Comment: You'd declaring the $regex variable on the command line, or inside a script? When I try on the command line I just get `=[regularexpression]: command not found`.

Comment: yes, typo, when declaring variable there is no need for `$` - corrected. you declare the variable in the script, if this whole thing is a script...if you run it in a bash command line, declare it there. but no need to declare, its just more readable

Comment: `sort | uniq` is better as `sort -u`.

Comment: yup, nice catch, as @Barmar mentioned, you can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`